# I am running my code on google colab. Am getting RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered.Error is showing for torch.manual_seed(seed)

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import random
total_steps = 1
seed = 42
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
```

Below is the error am getting
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 random.seed(seed)
5 np.random.seed(seed)
----> 6 torch.manual_seed(seed)
7 torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
8 tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

```
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/cuda/random.py in cb()
    109         for i in range(device_count()):
    110             default_generator = torch.cuda.default_generators[i]
--> 111             default_generator.manual_seed(seed)
    112 
    113     _lazy_call(cb, seed_all=True)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check output of `device_count()`. You may use out of range index.